# Projection using Inner product

Tags: quantum-mechanics

why is projection of A along e is
$\langle{e}|{A}\rangle |{e}\rangle$and not $\langle{A}|{e}\rangle |{e}\rangle$ ? 
e is a unit vector.

Comment: Define the context. Also notation is just notation.

Comment: It's Gram Schmidt procedure.

Answer (score 2):

In this rather sloppy language, what you (implicitly) assume is that you can write
$|A\rangle = \sum_f a_f|f\rangle\langle f|$, with the set of basisvectors $|f\rangle$ forming a complete set, i.e. $\langle e|f\rangle = \delta_{ef}$.

Then $\langle e|A\rangle|e\rangle = \langle e|\sum_f a_f |f\rangle\langle f|e\rangle = \sum_f a_f \langle e|f\rangle\langle f|e\rangle = \sum_f a_f \delta_{ef}\langle f|e\rangle = a_e$, which intuitively makes sense.

Comment: What is $\langle f| $ in $|A\rangle = \sum_f a_f|f\rangle\langle f|$?

Comment: @mum there’s a problem here… if you don’t know what is $\langle f\vert$ then what is the meaning of your $\langle e\vert A\rangle$, which contains $\langle e\vert$?